# SharePoint Wiki Page CheckIn not working for IE after adding Angular code in web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, angular2

This is a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Wiki Site and a new Angular 7 app is embedded to Content editor web part in master page. Once a Wiki Page is edited CheckIn ribbon button can be clicked. But the once Continue is clicked in confirmation popup nothing happens. This happens only in Internet Explorer and in Chrome works fine.

If that Angular 7 app is removed CheckIn functionality works fine. Seems there is some conflict due to Angular code.

Comment: You see that F12 is errors code JS?